# Cannot use ActionListener

Tags: java

i have been trying  to figure the problem with this code, Whenever I use the ActionListener to create an event for convertbutton it shows me this error:
(I wrote this code from my textbook and it worked with most of my colleages but i dont know why it doesnot work with me)

```
    error: cannot find symbol
        private class ConvertButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      symbol:   class ActionListener
      location: class KiloConverter
    java:37: error: cannot find symbol
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      symbol:   class ActionEvent
      location: class KiloConverter.ConvertButtonListener
    cannot be converted to ActionListener
            convertButton.addActionListener(new ConvertButtonListener());
    Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
    3 errors
   The following error occurred while executing this line:
    Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

and here's my code:

myFrame:

```
package myframe;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("My First Frame");
        
        
        
    }
    
}
```

KiloConverter:

```
package myframe;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KiloConverter extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel; 
    private JButton convertButton;
    private JLabel Label;
    private JTextField kiloTextField;
    final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 400;
    final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 150;
    
    //Constructor
    public KiloConverter() {
        setTitle("Kilometer Converter");
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildPanel();
        add(panel);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    private void buildPanel(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        Label = new JLabel("Enter the distance in kilo");
        kiloTextField = new JTextField(10);
        convertButton = new JButton("Convert");
        convertButton.addActionListener(new ConvertButtonListener());
        panel.add(Label);
        panel.add(kiloTextField);
        panel.add(convertButton);
    }
    
    private class ConvertButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            final double conversion = 0.6214;
            String input;
            double miles;

            input = kiloTextField.getText();
            miles = Double.parseDouble(input) * conversion;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input+" Kilometer is equal to " + miles +" in miles.");
        }
    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new KiloConverter();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *java:37: error: cannot find symbol* - is telling you it doesn't know what an `ActionEvent` is because you didn't import the class. Read the API to find out what package it belongs to.

Comment: As per the above comment, you'll need to add the correct import. Here is a link to the javadoc for ActionListener: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html Note at the top of the page how ActionListener is part of the `java.awt.event` class, so using `import java.awt.event.ActionListener;` or `import java.awt.event.*;` would do the trick.

Comment: @sorifiend i've imported them but still it shows a red line under the import

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you need to use the correct ActionEvent import.

Import the `java.awt.event.ActionListener`.

That should do it.

Have a nice day!

:D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i have imported it but it show a red line under.

Comment: What does the error imply?

Comment: When you hover your mouse over the error, what does the IDE say?

Comment: @Robatortas it says "cannot find symbol" and "convertButton.addActionListener(new ConvertButtonListener());" says "cannot be converted to ActionListener"

Comment: Maybe you have two different imports so the program gets confused. That is my guess. Let me keep thinking

Comment: I know! what the answer is!

Comment: @Robatortas what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably because of wrong imports, or because you didn't do this.

In the line:

```
convertButton.addActionListener(new ConvertButtonListener());
```

it doesn't cast ActionListener to the "new ConvertButtonListener()"

it should be like this:

```
convertButton.addActionListener((ActionListener) new ConvertButtonListener());
```

Try it out and see if the problem is solved, if not. Its definitely imports.

I copied the code with my machine and works perfectly fine. So if the answer I just said did not work. It has to be imports.

Have a nice day!

If you have more questions feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks! the red line just went off. but now the last two imports here have a red lines: "package myframe;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;" and the code doesn't work :(

Comment: Quite strange, what JDK are you using for compilance?
And what do the new errors imply?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2 and the error is the same as before "cannot find symbol"

Comment: But, what JDK are you using to compile?
IDE's are another thing.
Examples of IDE's: Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans, Visual Studio.
Examples of JDK's: JDK 1.8, JDK 1.16.

JDK stands for Java Development Kit, its for developers.
So now with all this information in hand, could you tell me what JDK you use to compile?